# find pair from list that give highest absolute difference

Tags: list, indexing

Its given list of numbers . How to make function, that will search out all those pairs in it, that give highest absolute difference. Let function return list of pair of indexes, that are determining found pair. Let not be changing entry list. Case: for entry list [1, 4, 3, -1, 0, 3.5, 4] function has to return [[1, 3], [3, 6]].

Should I find first maximum or minimum and compare or what to do  ?

Comment: You answered the question in your last sentence.

Comment: How can [3, 6] be a result?

Comment: @7stud I think he wants the indexes of the items. If those are indexes, you get 4 (twice) and -1.

Comment: @Renan yes but, what if there is 2, 3, 4 max equal numbers...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this:

```
findPair = function(inputArray) {
var resultArray = []
    difference = 0;
resultArray.push([]);
for (var i=0; i<inputArray.length;i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<inputArray.length;j++) {
        if (Math.abs(inputArray[i] - inputArray[j]) > difference) {
            difference = Math.abs(inputArray[i] - inputArray[j]);
            resultArray[0][0] = i;
            resultArray[0][1] = j;
        }
    }
}
for (var i=0; i<inputArray.length;i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<inputArray.length;j++) {
        if ((Math.abs(inputArray[i] - inputArray[j]) === difference) && !((resultArray[0][0] === i) && (resultArray[0][1] === j)) && !((resultArray[0][0] === j) || (resultArray[0][1] === i))) {
            resultArray.push([i,j]);
        }
    }
}
return resultArray;
}
```

In first loop we find pair with max defference, and then in second loop find repeats of this. 
This is jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/4CbsT/

Comment: thanks but i cant understand this, Is this in python language? I think there is much an easier way

Comment: yes in python please ... but i think i understand it ... 
def findPair(inputlist)
difference=0
pairs=[];
for i in inputlist: (should i put Range(inputlist) or just input list); for j in inputlist
etc